# Calculo Probabilidades T-Student no R

Tags: r, matemática

Eu tenho a média e o desvio padrão da minha distribuição:

```
mean = -0.49 ; sd=3.029041
```

Como faço para calcular a probabilidade de `y` estar um desvio padrão abaixo da média utilizando a `T-Student` com 85 graus de liberdade? Seria: `P(y< média(y)-sd(y))`?

```
1-pt(mean-sd, df = 85, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

Está correto ou eu deveria fazer assim:

```
1-pt(((mean-sd-mean)/sd), df = 85, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

Editado:

Eu quero calcular essa Probabilidade `P(x< média(x)-sd(x))` utilizando a tabela `T-Student`. Como a `média` e o desvio padrão é amostral eu devo usar a distribuição `T-Student`, para isso devo padronizar: `t = (X - meadia(x))/Sd(x) ~ t-Student`. Correto?

Como não se trata da media amostral não preciso usar o `raiz` de `n`. Certo então no meu caso o `X` seria: `X = média(x)-sd(x)`

Padronizando para `T-Student`:

```
t = (X - media(x))/Sd(x) = (média(x)-sd(x) - media(X))/Sd(X)
```

Dessa forma o que quero calcular:

```
P((x< média(x)-sd(x)) = P (X - media(x))/Sd(x))< (média(x)-sd(x) - media(x))/Sd(x) = P (t < (média(x)-sd(x)-media(x))/Sd(x)))
```

Esta correto? Como fazer isso no R?

Comment: Esta média e este desvio padrão são da distribuição ou de uma amostra com tamanho igual a 86?

Comment: Da amostra com tamanho igual a 86.

Answer (score 5):

Não deveria fazer este cálculo de nenhuma destas maneiras. Da maneira como está formulada, a pergunta não me parece fazer muito sentido. A distribuição t de Student está sempre centrada em zero (a não ser que seja uma distribuição t de Student não-central, que não parece ser o caso). Assim, para o teu problema, tu vai estar sempre calculando uma probabilidade que não vai estar atrelada à estimação da média da tua amostra. Isto talvez não seja aparente com uma média pequena como a deste exemplo, mas aumente o valor da média para 100, por exemplo, e veja do que estou falando.

[A média amostral tem distribuição assintoticamente normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution#Examples), com média igual a µ e variância σ^2/n, onde µ é a média populacional, σ^2 é a variância populacional e n é o tamanho amostral. Assim, fica fácil ver que podemos utilizar a distribuição normal para calcular a probabilidade de uma variável aleatória estar um desvio padrão abaixo da média e um desvio padrão acima.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(86, mean=.5, sd=.3) # amostra aleatoria

media <- mean(x) # estimador pontual da media
erro_padrao <- sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)) # estimador do erro padrao

media-erro_padrao # media - erro padrao
[1] 0.4683514
media+erro_padrao # media + erro padrao
[1] 0.5321069

pnorm(media-erro_padrao, mean=media, sd=erro_padrao, lower.tail=TRUE)
[1] 0.1586553
pnorm(media+erro_padrao, mean=media, sd=erro_padrao, lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.1586553
```

A pergunta não está muito detalhada, então não consigo ter certeza sobre qual é a tua real razão em calcular estas probabilidades. Talvez se houver mais detalhes a respeito do teu real objetivo, as pessoas daqui do fórum sejam capazes de te ajudar um pouco mais.

---

Complemento após a edição da pergunta: para mim, este problema continua a não fazer sentido. Eu posso simplesmente estar com dificuldade de entendê-lo, mas vou tentar explicar em itens porque creio que ele não pode ser resolvido desta maneira.

1. De onde vieram os dados analisados? Dizer que uma distribuição tem média -0.49 e desvio padrão 3.029041 não significa muita coisa. Ela é simétrica em relação à média, por exemplo? Ela tem muitos outliers? Ela tem forma de sino? De U?
2. Por que usar a distribuição t? Mesmo que os teus dados tenham vindo de uma amostra, eu usaria a t apenas se eu tivesse alguma suspeita a respeito de caudas pesadas na tua distribuição. Além disso, o cálculo da padronização de variáveis só está definido para variáveis com distribuição aproximadamente normal. Mesmo que os teus dados tenham distribuição t, as caudas pesadas desta distribuição vão influenciar neste cálculo porque, bem, a tua variável tem distribuição t de Student e a padronização não está definida neste caso.
3. A fórmula (x-mean(x))/sd(x) só funciona se x tem uma distribuição aproximadamente normal devido ao [Teorema Central do Limite](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_central_do_limite). Este teorema só está definido para variáveis aleatórias com distribuição assintoticamente normal. Por isso resolvi este problema da maneira que apresentei anteriormente: [a média amostral tem distribuição assintoticamente normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution#Examples), não importando a distribuição das variáveis aleatórias

É possível fazer da maneira como tu está fazendo? Sim, mas não vai estar correto. Esta padronização proposta não existe para a t. Assim, tu vai obter sim algo parecido com um valor z, mas que não tem sentido real. Afinal, o que significa (x-mean(x))/sd(x) no conteto da t? Qual a distribuição desta transformação? Eu não sei se é t. Eu só conheço o caso em que x é normal ou o caso em que utilizamos a média amostral.

Se os teus dados forem normais, utilize a acumulada da normal diretamente. E não é necessário sequer padronizar a variável, pois é possível calcular estas probabilidades diretamente. A não ser, claro, que tu queira encontrar estes valores numa tabela. Aí sim pode fazer esta transformação sem problemas.

Comment: Oi editei a pergunta. Pode checar? Obrigada!

Comment: Obrigada, Marcus. Acho que vou voltar para os livros. A minha ideia era a seguinte: essa é a minha tabela t student `tabela_student=qt(1:99/100, df=length(thau)-1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)` . Uma vez que eu assumo que x tenha distribuição normal e que o desvio padrão tenha distribuição qui quadrada, eu achava que fazendo essa padronização acima eu "sairia" na distribuição t e poderia calular qlqer probabilidade utilizando essa tabela.

Comment: Só mais uma correção: se a variável aleatória x tem distribuição normal e foi tomada uma amostra sua de tamanho n, então o que tem distribuição qui-quadrado com (n-1) graus de liberdade é ((n-1)/sigma^2)*S^2, onde S^2 é o estimador da **variância** amostral.